# I want to make an Exam reminder app

Tags: android

I am going to make an app which will help me to remind my exam dates and times.
**I will set my exam date and time to my app and when my exam will come closer , my app will alert/notify me that "your exam is tomorrow"**

Now how I will start this project ?? Which topic I will need to complete this project ??

I just need suggestions...

**I tried to take date and time input from user**

```
package com.nitol.aust.cse.dateandtimepicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

TextView tv;
Button btn;

int year, month, day, hour, minute;
int yearFinal, monthFinal, dayFinal, hourFinal, minuteFinal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this, year,month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    yearFinal = year;
    monthFinal = month + 1;
    dayFinal = dayOfMonth;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog( MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this,
            hour, minute , false);

    timePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    hourFinal = hourOfDay;
    minuteFinal = minute;

    tv.setText("Year "+yearFinal+"\n"+
            "Month "+monthFinal+"\n"+
            "Day "+dayFinal+"\n"+
            "Hour "+hourFinal+"\n"+
            "Minute "+minuteFinal+"\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Android and SQLite, Android and date handling, notifications on Android. Not necessary, but can be useful: Android and Alarms.

Answer (score 0):

First you should design your layouts and Activities.

- To Insert Exam
- List Exam
- Store the each exam in database table(Firebase,Appengine ).
- write a query comparing today's date and exam date from table.
- If exam date equals today's date+1 then send notification using
  firebase.
- Run that query once in 24 hours using Cron Servelet.

You will finish up with your project.

Comment: "firebase" or "SQLite" , which is easy ??

Comment: @Nitol Neel SQlite will be easier.

Comment: i know something about SQLite and also can save data into database. Hope that i can save the exam date and time in database. But then how to show this in future as a alert ??

Comment: @Notol Neel Using FCM take look at this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/

Comment: This is online service... Can't i do it in offline ?

Comment: Yeah you can do it offline using services with alaram manager and running service should not be forceclosed.